# Text Detection with CV2 + Pytesseract Picking up Every Shadow as Text

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory, ocr, python-tesseract, bounding-box

This is my first time using this site. I'm a beginner attempting to create a script in Google Colab using CV2 and Pytesseract that detects and blurs all text in an .mp4 file and outputs the result as a blurred .mp4. However, I noticed that things like eyes and mouths and shadows were being blurred out. I adjusted the script to display bounded boxes instead of blur to see how much non-text items were being picked up as text. It turns out almost every shadow was being detected as text. I played with the psm config but it didn't make a difference. I would appreciate some help.

I have attached an image to show a concrete example of what I'm talking about.
[Output Frame Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbkXq.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Set the path to the tesseract executable file
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = ( r'/usr/bin/tesseract' )

def process_frame(frame):
    # Convert the frame to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
    
    # Perform adaptive thresholding to create a binary image
    binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 71, 20)

    # Apply erosion to remove small noise
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    binary = cv2.erode(binary, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Find contours in the binary image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    # Loop over the contours
    for contour in contours:
        # Get the bounding rectangle of the contour
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        
        # Only process the contour if it is small (to avoid processing faces)
        if w * h < 20000:
            # Extract the region of interest (ROI) from the frame
            roi = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            
            # Convert the ROI to grayscale
            gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
            # Perform adaptive thresholding on the ROI to create a binary image
            binary_roi = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_roi, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 71, 20)
            # Same changes as for the main binary image
            
            # Use pytesseract to recognize text in the ROI
            config = r'--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ --tessdata-dir "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata"'
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(binary_roi, config=config)
            
            # Add the text and bounding box to the output frame
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
    return frame


# Set the input and output file paths
input_path = ("/content/drive/Shareddrives/325.mp4")
# output_path = ("/content/" + CreativeADID + "_BoundingBoxes-model-1.mp4")
output_path = ("/content/testing_BoundingBoxes.mp4")

# Open the input video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_path)

# Get the video codec and FPS information
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# Get the frame size of the input video
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Create a VideoWriter object to write the output video file
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

# Process each frame of the input video
while True:
    # Read a frame from the input video
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Break the loop if the end of the video is reached
    if not ret:
        break

    # Draw bounding boxes around the text regions of the frame
    frame = process_frame(frame)

    # Write the processed frame to the output video file
    out.write(frame)

# Release the resources
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried adjusting the psm with no noticeable difference in the output

I tried reworking the script to use EAST but got frustrated with the "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found" error, but that's another story

Comment: Can you post original image?

Comment: Still learning the most effective way of using this site. Did you happen to check out the "Output Frame Example" link above? I could provide another example if that would help.